# How to mock a class throughout the system using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method like this which I am trying to test using Mockito:

```
public class MiscUtil{

    public int getValue(String key){
        Properties properties = new Helper().getProperties() //This is the method 
                                                             //I need to mock
        return properties.get(key)
    }
```

Here is the test class :

```
public class MiscUtilTest{

public void testGetBooleanValue() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(MY_SPECIAL_INT_PROPERTY, 10);
    // Mock Helper
    Helper mock = Mockito.mock(Helper.class);
    // mock the method getProperties()
    Mockito.when(mock.getProperties()).thenReturn(properties);

    // Assert that the getValue() method 
    Assert.assertEquals(10,MiscUtil.getValue(MY_SPECIAL_int_PROPERTY));
```

However, the method doesn't get mocked. Do I have to pass the actual mocked instance into the MiscUtil class in order for mocking to take effect? The MiscUtil class doesn't let me pass the Helper object to it. It is very easy to mock a particular method of any class in JMockit even though the upper classes may not have access to it. Is it possible to do this in Mockito?

Comment: `Do I have to pass the actual mocked instance into the MiscUtil class in order for mocking to take effect?` Yes. That's one solution.

Comment: You might gain some insight from [my article on the Mockito wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test only the behavior of the `getValue()` method , you will need to **provide** (mock) the objects the method needs.

The `MiscUtil` class, needs an instance of `Helper` object. So you need to pass this object via MiscUtils' constructor (or another way), because it's a **dependency** of this class.

So everything that it's a **dependency** and you **don't** want to test should me mocked, and you will call only the real method that you want to test ( `MiscUtil.getValue(MY_SPECIAL_int_PROPERTY)` ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the mock object back, otherwise, Mockito will not know its getProperties method is invoked.

You need to add a method to inject Helper in your MiscUtil class:

```
private Helper helper;
public Helper getHelper()
{
     return helper;
}
public void setHelper(Helper helper)
{
     this.helper = helper;
}
```

Update MiscUtil class to use the Helper you injected:

```
    public int getValue(String key){
    Properties properties = getHelper().getProperties() //This is the method 
                                                         //I need to mock
    return properties.get(key)
}
```

Then set back this mock object back into MiscUtil:

```
MiscUtil.setHelper(mock);
```

And now, Mockito mocking should work

Comment: Mockito has a lot less functionality than JMockit. Can Mockito be used to test static methods? If there is a way to do this I can get around this problem.

Comment: No, you cannot.
It actually makes sense. The mocked object should be injected into the class as a dependency.

Comment: @SalilSurendran Yes, you *can* do it while using Mockito, provided you also use PowerMockito (the part of the PowerMock library which supports Mockito) for such things as mocking `final` and `static` methods, constructors, and `new`-ed objects.